# Expected JS module, server responded with MIME?

Tags: javascript, import, server, node-modules, mime

I'm new to JS and I've been turning one of my scripts that was Node to be attached to a webpage for canvas graphics.

I've made it have a .mjs extension and seems to be mostly working, but the modules that were in the script are all broken. The specific error in the webpage console, once per module, is:

> Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

What does this mean and how do I fix it? It's also returning a 404 on my .env but that's less important.

The way I'm importing things into the script is
`import fetch from '/node_modules/node-fetch';`
and in the HTML on the live server is
`<script type="module" src="script.mjs"></script>`

if it matters, the script references all have status 301 and the modules have status 200 on the network tab. I'm hosting the webpage using the "Live Server" extension for VSCode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to that the server is serving the .mjs with wrong Content Type. So try to convert the .mjs to .js or use [Http-server](https://github.com/http-party/http-server#readme) instead.
As in this link [mdn module guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) it states that http-server and github pages work correctly with .mjs.
You can also try to use a bundler such as Parcel or webpack.